# PL/SQL Stored procedure

Tags: plsql

I want to delete record from table based on id using stored procedure. Id value has to be passed as parameter. But while trying this code, data in the table is not deleted. Can anyone help me to get through this

```
 create or replace procedure PROC_INV_DELETE(num in number)
 is
begin

  delete from table_name
  where id = '&num';
  commit;

end;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do your job :

```
create or replace procedure PROC_INV_DELETE(num in number)
 is
begin

  delete from table_name
  where id = num; ---No need to use & and '' here
  commit;

end;
/
```

Calling:

```
declare

a number:= '&num' ; 

Begin

  PROC_INV_DELETE(a); 

end;
/
Enter value for num: 4
old   3: a number:= '&num' ;
new   3: a number:= '4' ;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Not like this. while executing procedure it should ask for dynamic value from user.

Comment: Procedure remains the same, Only you have to change the way you call it. See my post once again,

Comment: @Anonymous - The procedure itself can't be interactive.  That's why you need a "wrapper" that is.  The wrapper gets the value from the user then passes it to the procedure.  Don't forget to add exception handling!

Comment: The client application needs to prompt, validate, and pass the input value to the procedure. Procedures don't prompt.